# How to resize the ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=memoryview) without Image.open at first

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-photoimage

I am 100 percent sure that this question is never asked before. I uploaded an image to postgres database. I pulled it to view and currently I am able to view it with this code down below:
row[19] is a memoryview. Thats why I was not able to open it with Image.open and resize it.

Additional info: The memoryview looks like this `<memory at 0x000001D203D73100>`

```
imge = row[19]
imgd = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=imge)
image_label.image = imgd
image_label.config(image=imgd)
```

The problem is I could not manage to resize it. Here are the ways I failed

```
imge = row[19]
imgd = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=imge)
imgd = imgd.resize(180,180)
image_label.image = imgd
image_label.config(image=imgd)
```

I ended up with this:
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'

I also tried this, checked this method from its module page. This did not gave an error but nothing changed in the size of the image.

```
imge = row[19]
imgd = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=imge, size=(180,180))
image_label.image = imgd
image_label.config(image=imgd)
```

Comment: According to the official [document](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage): *size – If the first argument is a mode string, this defines the size of the image*.  That's why the `size` option does not work in your case.  You need to use `Image` class for image resize.

Comment: `PhotoImage` simply does not have the ability to arbitrarily resize images - it can only scale up or down (via `.zoom()` and `.subsample()`) by integer ratios.  You can certainly do the job with PIL/Pillow, you'd just need a different function (`.frombuffer()`, I think) to load your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do Image.open

```
from PIL import Image
i = Image.open("path2")
i.resize((width,height))
img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. I know how this method but in order to do this I need to save it from the database which I do not want to do. I want to view it through the database.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageTk.PhotoImage` class does not support image resize, you need to use `Image` class:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
...

imge = BytesIO(row[19])
imge = Image.open(imge).resize((180,180))
imgd = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imge)
image_label.image = imgd
image_label.config(image=imgd)
```

Comment: hi. Thank you for the effort but it did not work. I was hopeful when I first saw your answer however, I remembered that BytesIO does not support this kind of action. Here is the error code: AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Comment: It should work if `row[19]` is the raw data of an image.  How do you save the image to database?

Comment: it saved the data as memoryview object.